# Create view using count function

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, view

I created multiple choice question system and I created the following tables. I want a result display how many right answers as well as wrong answers chosen by the students.

**login table**

```
name        usergroup    matricno      
alex          1           ac91919      
sarah         1           ac92151
```

**Quiz table**

```
QuizID   QuizText
1        level 1
2        level 2
3        level 3
```

**Question table**

```
QuestionID QuestionText
1          Question1
2          Question2
3          Question3
```

**answer table**. where it has fk to question table and bit to determine whether the      answer is right [1-right 0- wrong]

```
answerID answer_question_id(fk) answertxt answer_isright
1          1                    answer1   1
2          1                    answer2   0
3          1                    answer3   0
4          2                    answer1   1
5          2                    answer2   0
6          2                    answer3   0
```

**result table** for every user that answers the quiz.  From table below, student matric no ac91919 answer quizid2 which is level 2.

```
ResultID   Result_Quiz_ID    MatricNo 
  1           2             ac91919
```

**resultdetail table** store the users answers. ResultDetail_ResultId(fk to resultID)         ResultDetail_AnswerId (FK to TblAnswers)

```
ResultDetailId      ResultDetail_ResultId      ResultDetail_AnswerId 
      1                      1                             2
```

from these table,  how do i create a **view** like this : for example, alex has 5 right answer, 10 wrong answer. this view only count the max resultid(latest result) for each user.

```
name       QuizTxt        RightAnswer    WrongAnswer        
alex       Level 1            5              10               
sarah      Level 2            3              9
```

database structure:

```
Table login

name varchar(55)
usergroup int
matricno varchar(20)

TblQuiz

Quiz_Id int 
Quiz_Name nvarchar(200) -- 


TblQuestions

Question_Id int 
Question_Quiz_Id int --(FK To TblQuizes) 
Question_Text nvarchar(200) 

TblAnswers

Answer_Id int 
Answer_Question_Id int --(FK To TblQuestions) 
Answer_Text nvarchar(200)
Answer_IsCorrect bit

 TblResults

Result_Id int 
Result_Quiz_Id int -- 

TblResultDetails

ResultDetails_Id int
ResultDetails_Result_Id int 
ResultDetails_Answer_Id int
```

Comment: Start by writing a query that returns the results that you want.  What have you tried?

Comment: i just know this query require pivot. but i dont know how and i need help

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar things in the past. You could make another table for the answers.
for each row will be an answer.   The advantage of this is you could display a single player or also what most people answered like a highest score.
You did not ask for any code so I assume you need a way of doing it.

You can loop trough the list of items by putting them in an array. Then you could put it in a listview or datagrid or what ever you need or want to build using a loop function. listviews and dataviews are most common but you could use a combobox etc. Since I don't know where you database is and what type I cannot help you with code. Generally it goes like this.

1. select what you need out of the database (could be all)
2. put the selected items database in an array.
3. loop trough the array.
4. load each item in it's control during the loop.

Here is an example of how to connect to a database and load it

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_dbconn_repeater

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
dim dbconn,sql,dbcomm,dbread
dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
data source=" & server.mappath("northwind.mdb"))
dbconn.Open()
sql="SELECT * FROM customers"
dbcomm=New OleDbCommand(sql,dbconn)
dbread=dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
customers.DataSource=dbread
customers.DataBind()
dbread.Close()
dbconn.Close()
end sub
</script>

<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="customers" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Companyname</th>
<th>Contactname</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>City</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("companyname")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("contactname")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("address")%></td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("city")%></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

There are many other ways of doing this like LINK() etc. Just use google or bing to find more ways.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: You can select the column in a specific row and display that. You can get anything anyway back from the database. The best thing is show your html code so we can help you better. Then tell us in the code what you need and where. Thanks!

Comment: BTW I did give you an example of loading a table. FYI

Comment: i want to create view and im using dbms mssql